# Hibernate Criteria most recent date field of Collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have Laboratories with a collection of states, here are my simplified Classes:

```
    LabState {
        private Integer id;
        private State state;
        private Date date;
        private String comments;
    }

    State{
        private Integer id;
        private String name;

    }

    Lab{
        private Integer id;
        private List<LabState> states = new ArrayList<LabState>();
        private Date date;
        private String name
    }
```

I want to get via Hibernate Criteria the Last State from a specific laboratory. in mySql this work fine:

```
SELECT ls.* FROM labs_states les INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT idLab, idLabState, MAX(date) AS lastDate FROM labs_states GROUP BY idLab)
        groupedLabs ON les.idLab = groupedLabs.idLab  AND les.date = groupedLabs.lastDate
```

**Edit: SearchMethod:**

```
   public List<Labs> search(LabSearch labSearch) {

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory();
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Lab.class);

            criteria.add(Restrictions.like("name", "%" + labSearch.getName() + "%"));

            if(labSearch.getState() != null){
                criteria.createCriteria("states").add(Restrictions.eq("state", labSearch.getState())).addOrder(Order.asc("date")).list().get(0);


            return (List<Lab>) criteria.list();
}
```

I don't nkow how to do this with Criteria, or if there is any other way to do

thanks

Answer (score 1):

to get the last state of the given lab

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Lab.class)
    .add(Restrictions.like("name", "%" + labSearch.getName() + "%"));
    .createAlias("states", "labstate")
    .createAlias("labstate", "state")
    .addOrder(Order.desc("date"))
    .setProjection(Projections.list()
        .add(Projections.property("labstate.id"), "id")
        .add(Projections.property("labstate.date"), "date")
        .add(Projections.property("labstate.comments"), "comments")
        .add(Projections.property("state.name"), "state"))
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean<LabstateDto>())
    .setMaxResults(1);

return (List<LabstateDto>)criteria.list();
```

if you want more than one lab with its last state returned you'll need another query which is not that easy because you have the backreference from Labstate to Lab ony in db and not in class.

Update: in response to your comment an alternative query

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Lab.class, "lab")
    .add(Restrictions.like("name", "%" + labSearch.getName() + "%"));
    .createAlias("states", "labstate")
    .add(Subqueries.proptertyEq("labstate.Id", DetachedCriteria.for(Lab.class)
        .add(Restrictions.propertyEq("id", "lab.id"));
        .createAlias("states", "lstate")
        .createAlias("labstate.state", "state")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("name", state));
        .addOrder(Order.desc("labstate.date"))
        .setProjection(Projection.property("labstate.Id"))
        .setMaxResults(1)
     );

return (List<Lab>)criteria.list();
```

Comment: thanks but as you mentioned, I need all the labs that have a particular state.
I solved using native SQL and then adding it to the entity Labs, which I dont know if it will be optimal.

Comment: what do you need the last of, the complete labstate or only the name of the state object?

Comment: I need a list of Labs that meet the search criteria, then I can get the state with Lab.getState().  But if I do a search by state, I just must to search in the current state of each laboratory.